# Join Org3 to network with separate ordering service and zookeeper-kafka

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Working on multiple organization for my `hyperledger fabric` network on `docker swarm`. each organization crypto material are on separate physical ubuntu 16.04 machine. following this example https://github.com/skcript/hlf-docker-swarm

I have successfully started my network with 2 orgs and zookeeper-kafka. both orgs are synced and working well.

Now i want to add 3rd orgs to network, i added new docker swarm worker and generate 3rd orgs artifacts.

here below the network architecture want to build:

[image]

i followed example to join 3orgs to network like https://github.com/alejandrolr/hyperledger-fabric-add-orgs and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKuGU5CYV_E but mostly they are with single orderer service.

Can anybody suggest steps or example to join 3rd orgs to running network with multiple ordering service on docker swarm ?

Comment: I managed to do this. i will update answer shortly.